# Select date format ddmmyyyy from oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select a date field from oracle database, using 
`select to_date(trndt, 'yyyymmdd') from cf20gldt`, but the system was showing an error.

Comment: `to_date()` converts a string to a *date*. You are looking for `to_char()` which converts a date to a string in a specified format (btw: **always** include the actual error message, we can not see your screen from over here)

Answer (score 16):

[Reference](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_nls_date_format_sysdate.htm)

Change it as `to_char`

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(trndt, 'yyyymmdd') FROM cf20gldt;
```

if your **trndt** column is not date type then you have to change it as

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(trndt), 'yyyymmdd') FROM cf20gldt;
```

**For example display system date**

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate,'yyyymmdd') FROM dual;
```

Comment: Your answer is correct so far, but you should never use to_date without specifying a format. Omitting the format makes your select statement dependent on the current regional settings, which may or may not match the format present in the date string.

Comment: @Naveen : what to do when i have to use "select * " in my query and need date in DD/MM/YYYY format

Comment: @user3782114, to do that you would use the following: `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY';`. But don't use `SELECT *`.

Comment: @user3782114 in realtime applcation development, select * from <table_name> is not recommended to get the data from DB. Need to mention what are the columns you need.

Answer (score 2):

To_date is to convert a column to date format . If your trndt is not date already then use below :

```
select to_char(to_date(trndt), 'yyyymmdd') from cf20gldt;
```

Or if your column trndate is already in date format then use below:-

```
select to_char(trndt, 'yyyymmdd') from cf20gldt;
```

Comment: Correct, but don't use to_date without specifying a format. See my corresponding comment on Naveen's answer.

Comment: I wrote to_date without any format so that it takes the database format and then use to_char for the required format (here yyyymmdd).

Comment: Yes, I understand this. But in case a date is stored in a string, it is stored in a certain known format. Name that format rather than have the dbms guess. A British user may have his/her setting to DD/MM/YYYY and his American collegue to MM/DD/YYYY. They do that, because they want to have dates displayed in the way they are used to (American or British). That must by no means affect the interpretation of the date stored as a varchar2 in the database.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
SELECT to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd') date,
        to_char(sysdate, 'hh24:mm:ss') hr
        FROM DUAL;
```

Change sysdate by your field type Date.