# how to get date in dd/mm/yyyy format in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Presently my query returning date as `05-04-17 06:31:17.881698000 PM`.

But I want to return like `20/10/201`. I have reffered [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629401/select-date-format-ddmmyyyy-from-oracle-database) But I am unable to intigrate this query in my query as they are taking columns individually.

```
select * from test_Table where reg_id = ?
```

Comment: Why have you tagged java?

Comment: `mysql` or `Oracle`?

Comment: it's Oracle query

Comment: You rever a link to SQL-Server?

Comment: please choose your tags accordingly, I was about to post a mysql query...

Comment: I have edited please find now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle's default date format is YYYY-MM-DD, WHY?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837974/oracles-default-date-format-is-yyyy-mm-dd-why)

Comment: You should be able to find answer by just googling it. In any case, look at to_char oracle function: [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm). Please note, you'll have to rewrite your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply give in the format as you like DD/MM/YYYY

```
select to_char(yourdate,'DD/MM/YYYY' ) from test_Table where reg_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using your query as-is (in general, using `SELECT *` is not a best practice), you can change the date format for your session with the following query:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY';
```

You can then run your query and the date should be returned in the format you want. Note that you'll have to do this with every session you start where you want the date in this format.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the below SQL Query to Query for the Date as the format you are asking for.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY]
```

You can query it directly or you can use it somewhere as variable to store it and then use it on the query you want.

Hope this help you.

Comment: This is not Oracle syntax